# How can I setup Ubuntu 20.04.1 to use the TPM 2.0?

Tags: 20.04, encryption, tpm

I want Ubuntu to use TPM 2.0 for encryption of the disk so that the encryption keys are stored in the TPM, and the password is asked on the login screen, just like Windows. I've done my research but, I haven't found any guides that talk about encryption of the disk using the TPM. Can someone please help?